# 4 lines of my class are not getting covered in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

4 lines from line `body = pdf.getContentAsPDF();` are not getting covered in my test class:

My class :

```
public class NMAT_ThankYou
{
    public id idPayment{get;set;}
    public Map<String,nm_Payment__c> mapOfPaymentRecord {get;set;}

    public NMAT_ThankYou()
    {
        idPayment = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('PaymentId');
        mapOfPaymentRecord =new Map<String,nm_Payment__c>();
        if(idPayment != null)
        {
            GETData();  
        }
    }    
    public void GETData()
    {
        List<nm_Payment__c> lstPayment  = [Select id, nm_OpportunityNew__r.Account.NMAT_Student_No__c,nm_OpportunityNew__r.Account.nm_RegistrationNumber__c,nm_OpportunityNew__r.Account.name,
                                           nm_OpportunityNew__r.nm_Year__c,nm_OpportunityNew__r.Is_Re_Registration_Payment__c,nm_Lead__r.NMAT_Registration__c, 
                                           nm_TransactionID__c, createdDate, nm_ModeOfPayment__c, nm_RefNo__c, nm_Amount__c, nm_PaymentType__c,nm_TransactionDate__c,nm_Lead__c,
                                           nm_Lead__r.nm_RegistrationNo__c,nm_Lead__r.Name,nm_Lead__r.NMAT_Year__c,nm_ActualPaymentAmount__c
                                           From nm_Payment__c 
                                           where id=:idPayment];
        System.debug('lstPayment Size-->'+lstPayment.size());
        if(lstPayment.size()>0)
        {
            for(nm_Payment__c objPayment :lstPayment)
            {
                mapOfPaymentRecord.put('StudentDetails',objPayment);
            }            
        }           
    }

    public void saveAsAttachment()
    {
        PageReference pdf = Page.NMIMS_Application_Payment_Receipt;
        pdf.getParameters().put('PaymentId',idPayment);

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        Date today = Date.today();
        Blob body;

        try{
            // returns the output of the page as a PDF
            body = pdf.getContentAsPDF();

            attachment.Body = body;
            // add the user entered name
            attachment.Name = 'Payment Receipt.pdf';
            attachment.IsPrivate = false;
            // attach the pdf to the Lead
            attachment.ParentId = mapOfPaymentRecord.get('StudentDetails').nm_Lead__c;
            insert attachment ;

         }catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Error Occurs while Saving Attachment -->'+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

And test class is

```
@isTest
 Public class NMAT_ThankYouTest{

   static testMethod void GETDataTest(){
     Blob body;
     nm_Payment__c Payment = new nm_Payment__c();     
     Lead leads = new Lead();

     leads.LastName = 'TestLast';
     leads.Institute_Name__c = 'TestInstitute';
     leads.Company = 'ABC';
     Insert leads;

     Payment.nm_TransactionID__c ='Tran0001';
     Payment.nm_ModeOfPayment__c = 'Online';
     Payment.nm_RefNo__c = '1285482';
     Payment.nm_Amount__c = 1100;
     Payment.nm_Lead__c = leads.id;
     Insert Payment; 

     apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('PaymentId',Payment.id);
     NMAT_ThankYou controller = new NMAT_ThankYou(); 
     PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/NMIMS_Application_Payment_Receipt');
     pageRef.getParameters().put('PaymentId', Payment.id);
     Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);        

     if (!Test.isRunningTest()){
        body = pageRef.getContentAsPDF(); 
     }
     else{
        body = Blob.valueof('Some random String');
     } 
     controller.saveAsAttachment();
     List<Attachment> attachments=[select id from Attachment where parent.id=:leads.id];
     //System.assertEquals(1, attachments.size());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where you are forced to modify your product code to work-around the lack of testability. The `Test.isRunningTest()` method is really meant to be used in product code (as it always returns true in a test) so put it here:

```
try{
    // returns the output of the page as a PDF (faked in test)
    body = !Test.isRunningTest()
            ? pdf.getContentAsPdf()
            : Blob.valueOf('Fake PDF content');
```

Answer (score 0):

this isn't currently supported in present system

[Salesforce Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HzknAAC)

Comment: I also read about it but thought there might be something we can do to covert these 4 lines